# The python program runs well in my local environment, but when uploaded to OJ, it was prompted with a runtime error

Tags: python, python-3.x

My Python program runs without any problems locally, but I receive a runtime error when running it on OJ. All the error messages show `exited with code 1`. I wonder what could be the problem.

Here is the link to the question (sorry, it doesn't seem to have an English version):  https://www.luogu.com.cn/problem/P5730

- `1 <= n <= 100`

Here is my code:

```py
digits_str_list = [
    ".XXX...X.XXX.XXX.X.X.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",
    ".X.X...X...X...X.X.X.X...X.....X.X.X.X.X",
    ".X.X...X.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...X.XXX.XXX",
    ".X.X...X.X.....X...X...X.X.X...X.X.X...X",
    ".XXX...X.XXX.XXX...X.XXX.XXX...X.XXX.XXX"
]

ans = [[] for _ in range(5)]
input()  # n
digits = input()
for i in range(5):
    for digit in digits:
        start_idx = eval(digit) * 4 + 1
        ans[i].append(digits_str_list[i][start_idx : start_idx + 3])
    print(".".join(ans[i]))
```

Apologies for my poor English, as it is not my native language. I hope it doesn't affect your reading, and feel free to point out any mistakes in my English.

- using a variable to capture the return value of `input()`, still RE.
- encapsulating it in a function and calling it using `if __name__ == '__main__':`, still RE.
- Replace `eval(digit)` with `int(digit)`.

Comment: Are you sure that the OJ is using Python 3?  2.x would cause this code to fail, due to the different behavior of `input()` - you would need to use `raw_input()` instead.

Comment: Yes, I am certain that Luogu OJ supports Python 3 and I did not choose the wrong version. Thx anyway.

Comment: Its possible it doesn't like the use of `eval()` as it allows arbitrary code execution. If you are just trying to transform the input (str) to an int instead of eval use `int(digit)`. If you really need to use `eval()` instead use `literal_eval()` from the **ast** module. `from ast import literal_eval  literal_eval(digit)`

Comment: Or, you call `input()` twice, and maybe its expecting only one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I have already tried using `int(digit)`, but still encountered the same runtime error. The input for that problem is supposed to have two lines: the first line containing number `n`, and the second line containing a string composed of `n` adjacent numeric characters.

Comment: Looks correct. Try removing more and more from the end of the code until that error goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved.

It turns out that there was a problem with the test cases on Luogu OJ. The input contained not only numeric characters but also whitespace characters. I'm really frustrated!

Here is the accepted code.

```py
digits_str_list = [
    ".XXX...X.XXX.XXX.X.X.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX",
    ".X.X...X...X...X.X.X.X...X.....X.X.X.X.X",
    ".X.X...X.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...X.XXX.XXX",
    ".X.X...X.X.....X...X...X.X.X...X.X.X...X",
    ".XXX...X.XXX.XXX...X.XXX.XXX...X.XXX.XXX",
]

ans = [[] for _ in range(5)]
n = input()
digits = input().strip()
for i in range(5):
    for digit in digits:
        start_idx = int(digit) * 4 + 1
        ans[i].append(digits_str_list[i][start_idx : start_idx + 3])
    print(".".join(ans[i]))
```